# Omit unnecessary properties in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this model:

```
var accountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    'seeker': {
        'fullName': String,
        'ageGroup': String,
        'education': String,
        'lookingForWork': String,
        'employmentStatus': String,
        'resume': String, // Filename ans stuff
        'mainWorkExp': String,
    },
    'employer': {
        'activationStatus': String,
        'companyName': String,
        'contactPersonFullName': String,
        'companyWebsite': String,
        'hiringRegion': [String],
        'logo': [],
        'description': String,
        'industry': String,
        'workingWithEOSP': Boolean,
        'booth': {
            'exists': Boolean, // Boolean to store with the employer created his/her booth or not
            'numberVisits': Number // number of clicks on the particular booth
            /* We can add more attributes here as we go */
        }
    },
});
```

It is exported and all is great. But there is one problem. If I try to create a seeker account using this script:

```
new account({
    'seeker': {
        'fullName': r.fullName,
        'ageGroup': r.ageGroup,
        'education': r.education,
        'lookingForWork': r.lookingForWork,
        'employmentStatus': r.employmentStatus,
        'mainWorkExp': r.mainWorkExp,
        'resume': r.file,
    },
}),
r.password,
```

In effect I get this in the database:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b4689ab6d68e81d32fda65e"
    },
    "seeker": {
        "fullName": "Alex Ironside",
        "ageGroup": "18 - 24",
        "education": "Some High School",
        "lookingForWork": "Less than 1 month",
        "employmentStatus": "Unemployed",
        "mainWorkExp": "Business, Finance or Administration. Includes all levels of office admin, accounting/bookkeeping, human resources, banking, etc."
    },
    "employer": { // The problem is right here!
        "hiringRegion": [],
        "logo": []
    }
}
```

So as you can see, I'm not mentioning the `logo`, or `hiringRegion` anywhere in the code, but it still gets created. Why is that? Does it have to do with the fact they're both declared as an `array` in the model? And how can I get around this issue?

I basically don't want the `employer` property/object to be created in the document created by my code. It should be only the `seeker` object, but I cannot just delete the `logo` and `hiringRegions` from the model, because I'm using them somewhere else, as an array.

The `r` object is short for `req.body`.

Comment: Shouldn't `logo` be defined as Array of something, as done above, where you declare `[String]`?

Comment: Declaring it as `[String]` doesn't solve the issue. And the `logo` property is an array that holds one object. That's how the package works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose arrays [implicitly have a default value of empty array](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays) so you can start using the array immediately. Do this instead:

```
'hiringRegion': { type: [String], default: undefined },
'logo': { type: [], default: undefined }
```

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: I believe you can just omit default and it should be undefined but anyway, same result